# Error in retrieving database to listview

Tags: android, database, sqlite

**My main Class**

```
 public class Tips2Main extends Activity{

DBOpener dbopener;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    dbopener = new DBOpener(this);    
}


 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
 super.onResume();

 // Configure the listview
 ArrayList<String> tips = new ArrayList<String>();
 ListView lstTips = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.lst_tips);
 lstTips.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tips));
 dbopener.createDatabase();

  Cursor Tips = dbopener.getTips();
  while (Tips.moveToNext()) {
      tips.add(Tips.getString(0)); // Get the current subj
  }
  Tips.close();
  lstTips.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tips));


  // Update the listview
  ArrayAdapter<String> ad = (ArrayAdapter<String>)lstTips.getAdapter();
  ad.notifyDataSetChanged();

   }

  //Close the DB when app pauses
    @Override
   protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  dbopener.close();
    }

   }
```

**My Database:**

```
    public class DBOpener extends Activity{
private static String DB_PATH = 
        "/data/data/sg.edu.iit.mns/databases/"; //path of our database
    private static String DB_NAME ="Tips"; // Database name
    private final Context myContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBOpener(Context context) {
        //super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1 );
        myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDatabase() {
        boolean dbExists = checkDatabase();
        if (!dbExists) {
            try
            {
                copyDatabase();
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(myContext, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    private boolean checkDatabase() {
        File database = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return database.exists();
    }

    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
        InputStream istream = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

        // Transfer bytes from istream to ostream
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = istream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            ostream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close streams
        istream.close();
        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();
    }

    public synchronized void close()
    {
        if(db !=null)
            db.close();
    }

    // Retrieve tips
    public Cursor getTips() {
        if (db == null)
            return null;
        return db.query("tips", new String[] {"Tips"},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

**Error log:**

```
     06-06 04:21:34.214: I/Database(719): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
     06-06 04:21:34.224: E/Database(719): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/sg.edu.iit.mns/databases/Tips", &handle, 2, NULL) failed
     06-06 04:21:34.224: D/AndroidRuntime(719): Shutting down VM
     06-06 04:21:34.224: W/dalvikvm(719): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {sg.edu.iit.mns/sg.edu.iit.mns.Tips2Main}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1812)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at sg.edu.iit.mns.DBOpener.createDatabase(DBOpener.java:41)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at sg.edu.iit.mns.Tips2Main.onResume(Tips2Main.java:33)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
     06-06 04:21:34.264: E/AndroidRuntime(719):     ... 12 more
```

when i try to populate my listview from database, it force closes the app. im not sure on how to error check and make it run. little help here.thank you. database in already inside the assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is your error "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file". I would  extend SQLiteOpenHelper in your DBOpener class. See this sample app, specifically the class in this URL for a quick template: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/src/com/example/android/searchabledict/DictionaryDatabase.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this links, It gives detail description about SQLite and samples too..

[AndroidSQLite](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

[SQLite Samples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android)

It may help you...

Answer (score 0):

1.) Why are you extendind your database class from `Activity` class?

Change

```
public class DBOpener extends Activity{
```

to

```
public class DBOpener{
```

---

2.) Add this method in your database class:

```
public DBOpener openDB() throws SQLException {
    db = dataHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

call this method from `copyDatabase()`

```
private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    InputStream istream = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
```

Hope it helps !!